# thread executor doesn't work spring batch

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-batch

I have a treatment that lasts 9 minutes, I would like to reduce the execution time by using thread-executor.

My reader reads 1200 lines in database and makes a UNPIVOT which gives me 56 036 lines to write in a csv file.

I have tried several ways but no difference in time, I have the impression that the configuration is not taken into account.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemReader<DmNebefPdhExportRetenuCSV> datamartEffRetenuItemReader(
        @Value("#{jobParameters['dateExport']}") Date dateExport) throws Exception {
    PagingQueryProvider query = createEffRetenuQuery();
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("dateExport", dateExport);

    JdbcPagingItemReader<DmNebefPdhExportRetenuCSV> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
    reader.setDataSource(sdmDataSource);
    reader.setParameterValues(parameters);
    reader.setQueryProvider(query);
    reader.setFetchSize(1000);
    reader.setPageSize(1000);
    reader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(DmNebefPdhExportRetenuCSV.class));

    return reader;
}

@Bean
@StepScope
FlatFileItemWriter<DmNebefPdhExportRetenuCSV> exportEffRetenuItemWriter(
        @Value("#{jobParameters['dateExport']}") Date dateExport) {
    // Construction du Header
    StringHeaderWriter headerWriter = new StringHeaderWriter(EXPORT_EFF_RETENU_CSV_HEADER);

    String newExportFileVersion = getExportRetenuVersion(dateExport);

    // Nom du fichier d'export
    String csvFileName = createEffRetenuExportFileName(dateExport, newExportFileVersion);

    // Chemin complet d'enregistrement du fichier
    String exportFilePath = String.join("/", exportArchiveCreRetenuPath, csvFileName);

    // Définition du délimiteur et des champs à mapper
    LineAggregator<DmNebefPdhExportRetenuCSV> lineAggregator = effRetenuLineAggregator();

    // Put dans le context pour récupérer dans le listener
    exportEffRetenuJobListener.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("exportFilePath", exportFilePath);
    exportEffRetenuJobListener.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("csvFileName", csvFileName);
    exportEffRetenuJobListener.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("newExportFileVersion",
            newExportFileVersion);

    FlatFileItemWriter<DmNebefPdhExportRetenuCSV> csvFileWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
    csvFileWriter.setShouldDeleteIfEmpty(true);
    csvFileWriter.setHeaderCallback(headerWriter);
    csvFileWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(exportFilePath));
    csvFileWriter.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);

    return csvFileWriter;

}

@Bean
public Step exportCSVStep() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("exportCSVStep")
            .<DmNebefPdhExportRetenuCSV, DmNebefPdhExportRetenuCSV>chunk(100)
            .reader(datamartEffRetenuItemReader(WILL_BE_INJECTED))
            .listener(readListener)
            .writer(exportEffRetenuItemWriter(WILL_BE_INJECTED))
            .listener(writeListener)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .throttleLimit(50)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor ();
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(50);
    taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
    return taskExecutor;
}

@Bean
public Job exportEffRetenuJob() throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory
            .get("exportEffRetenuJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(exportEffRetenuJobListener)
            .flow(exportCSVStep()).end().build();
}
```

I've also tried with new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor().

Adding setFetchSize() and setPageSize() to my reader, treatment time reduced from 9 minutes to 10 sec.
But ThreadExecutor doesn't seem to work.

Logs :

Without TaskExecutor : 12,751 seconds

```
[2018-01-03 11:41:32,087] INFO  ExportEffRetenuJobListener - Start job exportEffRetenuJob - export month 04-2017 
[2018-01-03 11:41:44,838] INFO  ExportEffRetenuJobListener - End job : exportEffRetenuJob - export month : 04-2017 - statut : COMPLETED
```

With TaskExecutor : 11,328 seconds

```
[2018-01-03 11:42:55,439] INFO  ExportEffRetenuJobListener - Start job exportEffRetenuJob - export month 04-2017 
[2018-01-03 11:43:06,767] INFO  ExportEffRetenuJobListener - End job : exportEffRetenuJob - export month : 04-2017 - statut : COMPLETED
```

Test with 240 000 lines to read/write

with TaskExecutor : 123 seconds

Without TaskExecutor : 127 seconds

I think I'm not configuring the task executor well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a `corePoolSize`for your executor. The default is 1 so you would still get just one thread. Try setting `taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(50)` and rerun your job.

Comment: Adding this parameter doesn't change anything, but my problem is somewhere else, I didn't set pageSize and fetchSize in my reader.
after initializing these two values, treatment time is reduced from 9 minutes to 10 sec. But with or without setting poolSize it doesn't change anything, and I don't know why.

Comment: From what you say, my guess is that the bottleneck is not at reading end but at writing end. Reading 1200 rows from database should not be a problem. Can we take a look at your writer?

Comment: I added it, I dropped the use of the task executor, because the order of my request was no longer respected in csv file.
But I'm interested in understanding the configuration of the task executor.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. While running batch the log statements only mentioning `taskExecutor-1` i.e only one thread was getting created. I updated my `TaskExecutor`  bean as below and that solved my problem.

```
@Bean
        public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
            ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
            taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
            taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(20);
            taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(8)

            return taskExecutor;
        }
```

Looking at your use case if processing is not major bottleneck then i think  **Partitioning**  will be the best scaling option in this case. 
[Partitioning](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning)

Comment: It doesn't change anything, see my comment below [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48065089/thread-executor-doesnt-work-spring-batch#comment83124122_48067203)

Comment: Yeah, I just added it. (it's very short)

Comment: Maybe the gain is small because of the amount of data, I'm running more tests with more data.

Comment: Update with 240 000 lines to read/write, Have you another idea to configure task executor, or it works normally for you ?